# Can't get the latest SVN tagged version number using batch script

Tags: batch-file, svn

I'm trying to find the most recent version from a list of tags.

In the SVN repo browser, I have the following folders structure: 
[image: SVNrepo]

When I run `svn list URL/tags`, I get: 

`1.10.0/
1.10.1/
1.11.0/
1.11.1/
1.3.0/
1.3.1/
1.3.2/
1.4.0/
1.4.1/
1.4.2/
1.4.3/
1.4.4/
1.5.0/
1.5.1/
1.5.2/
1.5.3/
1.6.0/
1.6.1/
1.7.0/
1.7.1/
1.8.0/
1.8.1/
1.9.0/
1.9.1/
1.9.2/
1.9.3/
1.9.4/`

From some other answers, I tried adding a --limit flag but svn list doesn't seem to accept that.

I have the following code that returns 1.9.4 as the most recent version. 
%svnRoot% is repo browser URL/tags

```
set username=%1
set password=%2
set appName=%3
set svnRoot=%4

CALL :findMaxVersion "svn list --non-interactive --no-auth-cache --username %username% --password %password% %svnRoot%"
GOTO :EOF

:findMaxVersion
set maxMajor=0
set maxMinor=0
set maxPatch=0
for /f %%x in ('%1') do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=./" %%a IN ("%%x") DO (
        if %%a GTR !maxMajor! (
            set maxMajor=%%a
            set maxMinor=%%b
            set maxPatch=%%c
        ) else if %%a EQU !maxMajor! (
            if %%b GTR !maxMinor! (
                set maxMinor=%%b
                set maxPatch=%%c
            ) else if %%b EQU !maxMinor! (
                if %%c GTR !maxPatch! (
                    set maxPatch=%%c
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
set recentVersion=%maxMajor%.%maxMinor%.%maxPatch%
echo The final maximum version is: %recentVersion%
```

I'm not sure how to either change the order of the svn list nor the batch script to get 1.11.1 instead of 1.9.4. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Also useful https://model-technology.com/blog/powershell-training-sorting-version-numbers/

Comment: Well, your logic seems to be right (but I cannot test it now); you do not need to use two nested `for /F` loops though. The only thing I am missing is `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` somewhere on top...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With hints from [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1266278/how-to-sort-right-decimal-numbers) for directory tree like this (your case reproduced)

```
>dir /B
1.0
1.1
1.10.0
1.10.1
1.11.0
1.11.1
1.3.0
1.3.1
1.3.2
1.4.0
1.4.1
1.4.2
1.4.3
1.4.4
1.5.0
1.5.1
1.5.2
1.5.3
1.6.0
1.6.1
1.7.0
1.7.1
1.8.0
1.8.1
1.9.0
1.9.1
1.9.2
1.9.3
1.9.4
```

(you can get it from your tags locally with checkout `--depth immediates`)
I got **correctly sorted** versions (full list, sorry, getting only the last string will be your part of task) by using such PowerShell oneliner

```
Get-ChildItem "Path\To\Parent\Dir" -Name | sort-object { [regex]::Replace($_, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20) }) }

1.0
1.1
1.3.0
1.3.1
1.3.2
1.4.0
1.4.1
1.4.2
1.4.3
1.4.4
1.5.0
1.5.1
1.5.2
1.5.3
1.6.0
1.6.1
1.7.0
1.7.1
1.8.0
1.8.1
1.9.0
1.9.1
1.9.2
1.9.3
1.9.4
1.10.0
1.10.1
1.11.0
1.11.1
```